# Can someone provide the intuition as to why least squares and MLE lead to the same coefficient estimates for linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, linear

In books, I am seeing that the estimates for a linear regression are the same whether you do least squares estimation or maximum likelihood estimation (with certain assumptions).

I am not understanding how this is true.  Let's say the TRUE distribution of Y | X is something that is extremely non normal.  Least squares estimation makes no assumption on the distribution of Y | X, so you you can easily determine the coefficients for the equation.

Now, let's say you are a novice data scientist, and decide to estimate coefficients using MLE while making the assumption that Y | X is normal and has constant variance, even though the true distribution is very non-normal.

You are telling me that our coefficient estimates will be the same in both situations, as long as you make the assumption that the data is normal, even if it is not normal?

How does that work?

Comment: Because the maximum likelihood metric with  normal noise is mean  squared error... just like maximising Exp - (x-y)^2 is equivalent to minimising ( x-y)^2

Answer (score 1):

You can think of maximum likelihood as an algorithm, just like least square. If you examine the maths behind the two algorithms, you will find that in the case where you assume normality, it is the same as least squares. Note that if the data is not normal, then that doesn't affect the validity or unbiasedness of your estimate, since ML is equivalent to least squares. However, your inference (confidence intervals, p-values, etc.) would not be accurate.

More generally, applying ML to situations where you know the distributional assumptions are violated is an established method for getting estimates. It's variously referred to [estimating equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimating_equations) or [pseudolikelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolikelihood). There are various ways to derive correct confidence intervals and p-values that are not dependent on the validity of normality.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Tim Mak is perfect and brings some further readings about what happens out of the usual distributional assumptions. But I would like to bring another view or intuition on the matter.

---

> You are telling me that our coefficient estimates will be the same in both situations, as long as you make the assumption that the data is normal, even if it is not normal?

Yes and no matter what you assume really. You can always get those parameters, using the very same method of least-square or MLE, with arbitrarily false assumptions. At worst your model fit will be bad (and wrong). People often fit a linear model and look afterwards at the error distribution: if it is not gaussian you might find that a better model is needed.

### Intuitively

First, let's remember that the MLE is a bayesian account of linear regression and treats the data themselves as random variables. It gives a probabilistic model of the data, and hence we ought to start with a distribution somewhere (the assumption on the error is a good place to start). 
On the other hand, a least-square estimation is a simple approach for parameter estimation, we only assume a model and a measure of errors, parameters are the variable. Gauss himself, by trying to incorporate a probability density on the error of such model came up with the "gaussian" as we can read on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares):

> He then turned the problem around by asking what form the density should have and what method of estimation should be used to get the arithmetic mean as estimate of the location parameter. In this attempt, he invented the normal distribution.

In one case (LSE) we find the parameter $\beta$ such as the euclidian distance (equivalently the mean squared error) is minimised. Here we decide to **measure** the error as the square distance.

In the other (MLE) we *expect* an error distributed normally around the line $y = \beta x$, which means an error that occurs more or less likely depending on the **squared distance** between data pairs. Then the parameter estimate that maximizes the probability of our data under this "error expectation" (or assumption) are the same parameters that we found by deciding to take the square distance as our error metric.

It simply is due to *how* you measure errors or discrepancy between your model (here we say a linear one such as $\beta x$) and your observables ($y$). Both LSE and MLE rely on measuring this as related to the square distance between those, although from a different starting point or way of thinking.
It can be helpful to remember that gaussianity in general "pairs well" with 2-norm errors (or also that laplacian distribution "pairs" with 1-norm errors...).

---

### More maths

If might feel natural to come back to the equations anyway...

The key element is simply that both the classical Least Square Estimate and the Maximum Likelihood Estimation for linear regression (with gaussianity assumption for errors) rely on the **square distance** between each data point pairs $(y_i, \beta x_i)$ as an error metric or measure of discrepancy between both datasets.

- For the least-square perspective, it feels natural to use the euclidian distance to measure how far apart our model $\beta x_i$ and the observable $y_i$ are. So our cost function will be of the form:
  $$
  \sum_i(y_i - \beta x_i)^2
  $$
- For the MLE, it is our most uninformative choice to assume a normally distributed error of data around the model mean for a given standard deviation (which is like saying that the error should remain evenly distributed around 0, a nice euclidian symmetry as offered by the square distance we see in the exponential $e^{-1/2(\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma})^2}$). So all we insist on is having a model of $y$ such as:
  $$
  y = \beta x + \epsilon \\
  \text{with}:~~\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)
  $$

And this gives us
$$
\implies ~~ y \sim \mathcal{N} (\beta x, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} . e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(y-\beta x)}{\sigma}\right)^2}
$$
Meaning that once again, if we were to find the most likely $\beta$ for such i.i.d. data we end up minimizing $$\sum_i(y_i - \beta x_i)^2$$